# How to go about benchmarking a software rasterizer

Tags: c++

Ok, ive been developing a software rasterizer for some time now, but have no idea how to go about benchmarking it to see if its actually any good.... i mean say you can render X amount of verts ant Y frames per second, what would be a good way to analyse this data to see if its any good? rather than someone just saying
"30 fps with 1 light is good" etc?

Comment: Are you asking what the standard measurements are, or what the standard benchmarks are that result from those measurements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you want to measure? I suggest fillrate and triangle rate. Basically fillrate is how many pixels your rasterizer can spit out each second, Triangle rate is how many triangles your rasterizer + affine transformation functions can push out each second, independent of the fillrate. Here's my suggestion for measuring both:

To measure the fillrate without getting *noise* from the time used for the triangle setup, use only two triangles, which forms a quad. Start with a small size, and then increase it with a small interval. You should eventually find an *optimal size* with respect to the render time of one second. If you don't, you can perform blending, with full-screen triangle pairs, which is a pretty slow operation, and which only burns fillrate. The fillrate becomes *width x height* of your rendered triangle. For example, *4 megapixels / second*.

To measure the triangle rate, do the same thing; only for triangles this time. Start with two tiny triangles, and increase the *number* of triangles until the rendering time reaches one second. The time used by the triangle/transformation setup is much more apparent in small triangles than the time used to fill it. The units is *triangle count/second*.

Also, the overall time used to render a frame might be comparable too. The render time for a frame is the derivative of the global time, i.e *delta time*. The reciprocal of the delta time is the number of *frames per second*, if that delta time was constant for all frames.

Of course, for these numbers to be half-way comparable across rasterizers, you have to use the same techniques and features. Comparing numbers from a rasterizer which uses per-pixel lighting against another which uses flat-shading doesn't make much sense. Resolution and color depth should also be equal.

As for optimization, getting a proper profiler should do the trick. GCC has the GNU profiler gprof. If you want an opinion on clever things to optimize in a rasterizer, ask that as a seperate question. I'll answer to the best of my ability.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to determine if it's "any good" you will need to compare your rasterizer with other rasterizers. "30 fps with 1 light" might be *extremely* good, if no-one else has ever managed to go beyond, say, 10 fps.